# limit(long) difference order in a pipeline

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

What is the difference between

```
stream.map().limit(5).terminalOperation()
```

and this line

```
stream.limit(5).map().terminalOperation()
```

the both lines will return the same result, but which one is more optimized and will not consume more time and resources ? and why ? and how many times the map will be called in each case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how many times the map will be called in each case?

The answer depends on the terminal operation, not on the order of `map` and `limit`.

The terminal operation may consume just one element (`findFirst()`) or all elements (`collect()`).

Either way, the terminal operation dictates the number of elements on which `map` is performed, which should be identical in both cases.

For example, if you collect the elements to a `List`, assuming the `Stream` source has at least 5 elements, `map` will be executed 5 times for each pipeline.

You can verify that by adding a `println` statement to the `map` step:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList ("a","b","c","d","e","f");
list.stream().map(l->{System.out.println ("map1 " + l);return l +"44";}).limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
list.stream().limit(5).map(l->{System.out.println ("map2 " + l);return l +"44";}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will output:

```
map1 a
map1 b
map1 c
map1 d
map1 e
map2 a
map2 b
map2 c
map2 d
map2 e
```

Either way, `map` is not executed for the 6th element.

As to which variant to prefer, I'm assuming they'll have similar running time, but that depends on the actual implementation.